# Does Oracle use temp tables during backup procedures

Tags: sql, oracle

Does Oracle make use of temp tables during backup procedures?

This has brought up many conversations in the break room, but we are limited in our expertise.

I'm pretty sure, please correct me if i am wrong, but to fully qualify for ACID - you need a way to store the data when the database is taken offline, even for a moment.

SQL Server writes to the transaction log, then will catch up after the DB comes back online - but i am not sure if Oracle follows the same idea.

thank you

Comment: Oracle also has a transaction log. _"you need a way to store the data when the database is taken offline"_; this doesn't, surely, apply to backups as a backup is an offline operation. Or, do you not mean a technical backup but how data is written?

Comment: Ben, Thank you for the reply...  Your comment confuses me a little..  When a database is taken offline for a backup, the transaction log is populated with the transaction - this i understand, thank you for clarification.   But the transaction log is a different storage location (possibly a table in itself) that is outside of the table that is being backed up - is that a correct statement?

Comment: Not quite; I mean are you asking about _actual_ backups, i.e. copying the data to a different server for the purposes of restoring the database in the event of catastrophic failure in a possible future? There's no need to take a database offline to do this, which has me slightly confused :-).

Comment: i understand - thank you.  I was thinking that the database needed to be taken offline for a few moments to do a full backup.  thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you mean with "Backup" that a Tablespace or the whole database is taken to backup-mode with `ALTER TABLESPACE tbname BEGIN BACKUP` or `ALTER DATABASE BEGIN BACKUP` the database is not offline but the tablespace resp. the datafiles on the disk are not written into.

This is necessary to prevent a backup of the datafiles in an inconsistent state (fractured block). The blocks changed (called "dirty") during this process are written to the redo-logfile and applied later when `ALTER DATABASE END BACKUP` is issued.

Backups done with `RMAN` (Recovery Manager) dont need backup mode at all.